# How to remove appbar on web, while keeping it displayed on Android and iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to remove appbar when run on web, but running with Anroid and IOS it's display as normal.
please provide soution to me.

I try to add condition but it's not working.

I wanna remove appbar on web.

Comment: check if not web then add appbar else empty widget.

Comment: i try to use this solution, but it'not working.

Comment: Ex: appBar: GetPlatform.isWeb
                ? const SizedBox()
                : customAppBarwhiteBackground(
                    leadingWidth: 100.0, context: context), I use like this

Comment: did you restart the app run?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
   return AppBar(title: const Text("AppBar"),);
} else {
   return Container();
}
```

***************** OR *****************

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

kIsWeb ? appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("AppBar"),) : null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

appBar: kIsWeb ? null : AppBar(title: const Text("AppBar"),),
```

[image: demo]